# Multi-monitor support for Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1

I am running Windows 8.1 on a new Dell XPS laptop. I have attached a second screen via HDMI cable, and configured Windows to "extend the display". All of that is working fine.

Now, I'd like to configure Windows to display the taskbar on the second screen, as described here: http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2406969,00.asp.

However, the "Multiple Displays" options are not visible where they should be, see the screeshot below:
[image]

I don't know why the multi-display options are not available, does anyone know how to enable them?

I am definitely running Windows 8.1:
[image]
Thanks in advance.

**Update**

This is my screen resolution window below (for the second screen). It does have a warning saying "Your resolution is lower that 2048 x 1440. Some items might not fit on your screen.", which is because my main laptop monitor has a much higher resolution. I suppose that might be the cause of the problem?
[image: screen resolution window]

Comment: If you don't have the option then you are not running Windows 8.1.  The option did not exist in Windows 8.0.

Comment: I am definitely running 8.1 (see new screenshot in question)

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is both displays are not being detected.  You are extending your desktop to both displays right?

Comment: Yip, the 2nd display is detected and used to "extend" the display, its just that the 2nd monitor doesn't have a taskbar and I can't figure out how to add it.

Comment: I've hit the same issue, currently running latest NVIDIA drivers - http://superuser.com/questions/653141/windows-taskbar-not-extending-to-second-display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue. Looks like this is a bug in an update to windows 8.1. The options show up again if i set the Display settings to *larger* than default item size ("Change the size of all items"). Man what a stupid bug, more info: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a1dc4fa9-e3fd-4e1e-a174-5acde06a43e0/multiple-display-options-for-taskbar-missing-after-windows-81-update?forum=w8itprogeneral.

I went back to using Actual Multiple Monitor, but its having weird issues too : /

I was seeing the warning about resolution, but I don't see it anymore, and i still have the problem. So maybe its related, but not directly.

CORRECTION: I actually do see the warning about resolution only for my 2 secondary screens, not my primary screen (so maybe it is related).

UPDATE:

I found another crappy "solution". If you check the "Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays", the start bars also all show up. Unfortunately, this option kinda sucks when my laptop screen is like twice the resolution of my secondary screen.. ugh

**Update: A Better Solution:**

So I'm not entirely sure what I did, but I got things to work. I tried using the "Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays" option and scaling it to some middleground. Then  I wanted to try switching back, and for some reason the startbars are still there, and the screen resolution settings don't have a warning anymore. So maybe you can just fiddle with this junk til it works?

Comment: Yip, this is it. If I increase "the size of all items" from where is was (to massive), the multi-monitor options magically appear. Argh!

Comment: @BarryPitman updated with another "solution" that might work better for you than it does for me

Comment: @BarryPitman another update

Comment: That worked for me too. I also couldn't describe the exact process that made it work, but I now have the extra toolbar at normal display resolution after hacking around with the settings. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check for updated graphics drivers. It looks like Windows does not detect your second screen in a correct way. I have seen issues with this using old nVidia drivers and multiscreen setups where the extend settings was unavailable or immediately lost when applying the new settings even if the secondary monitor was detected.

Comment: I have updated my nVidia drivers to the latest versions, and still the same problem

Comment: How does your screen resolution Control panel look? I noticed that some old monitors and projectors are not detected automatically and then the extend to this screen and more was very strange. Is your monitor listed with model and details?

Comment: I have updated my post. My second screen was picked up automatically. The model is listed with its correct details as well.

Comment: Strange problem... What about the message about some items may not fit on the screen.. Why would that show up? The screens should be the size of their resolution. I run 4 screens on my laptop here, 3 full HD and one 1600x900 but I dont have that kind of warning on the smaller one. I still think it is something wrong with the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I too have Dell XPS laptop, but with 3 screens.

I found 2 workarounds:
(1) turn off the auto DPI scaling (i.e. using "Let me use one scaling level for all displays") or
(2) reduce resolution of main display to be closer to that of the others.
I think the 2nd is the least worst (because the auto DPI scaling is useful) and I could restore the resolution of the main display and still work OK (albeit with small icons) until next sign-in.

Based on this, I think the issue arises because the resolutions of my monitors are so different to the laptop's (1280x1024 cf. 3200x1800).